# Jquery найти элементы с атрибутом data-*

Tags: javascript, jquery

Чтобы не делать так:

```
$('*')
```

Можно ли как-то сделать вот так, что бы брались только элементы у которых есть атрибут data- (например data-test, data-bla) :

```
$('[data-*]')
```

?

Comment: нет, там сделать нельзя. Но можно использовать [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-function)

Comment: если это в продолжения вопроса как работает ангуляр - то ты идешь не в том направлении.

Comment: @Grundy на Jquery пишу мини framework

Comment: очень похоже на [XY-проблему](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy) - скорее всего основная проблема заключается в чем-то другом. Например неверном проектировании мини framework

Answer (score 1):

```
$("*").filter(function(){
  var attributes = this.attributes;
  for (var i = 0; i < attributes.length; i++) {
      if (attributes[i].name.indexOf("data-")==0) 
      return true;
  }         
  return false;
});
```

Вот так можно.

Comment: автор по всему документу хочет проверять

Comment: Поправил чтобы искало по всему )

Comment: Мде =) Так у меня уже написано, как то бы проще и быстрей работало что-бы =)

Comment: @bsbak, очевидно нужно ограничить набор элементов, которые надо применять. Сделать это можно двумя способами: 1. сузить область поиска со всего документа, до конкретного контейнера. 2. искать не все возможные атрибуты data, а только заданные. Можно использовать два подхода сразу.

Comment: @Moonvvell вместо цикла можно просто написать return $.isEmptyObject($(this).prop('dataset')))

Comment: @bsbak, _вместо цикла можно_ - сомнительно что создание объекта jquery будет быстрее чем простой цикл

Comment: @Grundy Будет так как объект уже создан здесь $('*')

Comment: @bsbak, и тут ты ошибаешься. Если посмотришь - конструктор вызывается тут _$(this)_, идет обращение к функции, весьма не простой, и внутри _isEmptyObject_ Тот же цикл, пусть и из одной итерации. вместо этой строки лучше: `$.isEmptyObject(this.dataset)`